# Where have I changed register variable value?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I was playing with `GDB`. `x/<op> $var` is the command to view the current values right? I don't realize what has caused the value of `x/d $rbx` to change from 28 to -5604 in following sequence of command, since I have not taken any new step using `stepi` or anything. Any iea?

```
(gdb) x/s $rbx
0x7fffffffe718:  "\034\352\377\377\377\177"
(gdb) x/d $rbx
0x7fffffffe718: 28
(gdb) x/s $rbx
0x7fffffffe718:  "\034\352\377\377\377\177"
(gdb) x/1ws $rbx
0x7fffffffe718:  U"\xffffea1c翿"
(gdb) x/1wd $rbx
0x7fffffffe718: -5604

(gdb) x/d $rbx
0x7fffffffe718: -5604

(gdb) x/s $rbx
0x7fffffffe718:  "\034\352\377\377\377\177"
(gdb) x/d $rbx
0x7fffffffe718: 28
```

Comment: Looks to me like gbd was first set up for a byte unit size (0x1c is 28 decimal). Then when you change it to word (4 byte) size it uses the entire value of 0xffffea1c, which is -5604 when printed as a signed decimal number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't realize what has caused the value of x/d $rbx to change from 28 to -5604

The value in memory at address `0x7fffffffe718` has *not* changed.

What changed is the number of bytes GDB examines by default.